# ActionListener class to write to a file from TextField and Button

Tags: java, user-interface, file-writing

I have created a GUI, and have read in a file of text into a TextArea in the GUI.

I am trying to allow the user to be able to write back to the file. I have a TextField (for the user to type text into) and a button (which I want to add an actionListener to) so that when text is entered into the TextField and the button selected, it writes it back to the file.

This is the code I have got so far, but when I select the button, it clears what is in the file and the text (which has been read in) and was in the JTextArea is now empty.

```
class WriteToFile implements ActionListener {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter( "File.txt" );
                        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter( writer );
                        txtSearch1.write( bw );
                        bw.close();
                        area.setText("");
                        area.requestFocus();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e2) {}
                }

    }
```

Comment: What's giving you trouble with that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It sounds like you have already written some code. Please post the portions that are related to your question. Also, what is your question? What part are you having trouble with? Do you know how to create an `ActionListener`? Do you know how to open a file and write to it? Both of these are well-documented and a google search will help.

Comment: The text area is now empty because of this line: `area.setText("");
`

Comment: Do you know how I can append to the file from what is entered into the textfield

Comment: What is `txtSearch1`?

Comment: txtSearch1 is the name of the textfield

Answer (score 0):

Read everything from the file first, then write to the file:

```
    File file = new File( "TestFileWriter.txt" );
    StringBuilder fileText = new StringBuilder();
    // Read the file first, then write to it
    try ( BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( file ) ) ) {
        String line;

        while( ( line = br.readLine() ) != null ) {
            fileText.append( line );
            fileText.append( System.lineSeparator() );
        }
    }

    try ( BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( file ) ) ) {
        bw.write( fileText.toString() );
        bw.write( "New text to add on the next line" );
    }
```

Comment: I am writing to a file from a TextField and JButton, which will then show in a TextArea (as I have read in the file to the TextArea). Do you know how I would do it, is it similar to your above answer?

Comment: I suppose I am confused what you're trying to do.  You have a file already created.  You want to write to it again.  The user inputs text into a TextField, and when they press a Button it writes/appends it to the file.  That is what you're trying to do, right?

Comment: yes. The file already exists and contains text. I have already read in the file to a text area. I have a text field and a button, where the user can write to the file and when they select the button it writes/appends to the file.

Comment: " it writes/appends to the file" - well, which is it? Should it write the text to the file, or should it append the text to the file?

Comment: Sorry I mean append to the file

Comment: @j.aje I have edited my post to show you how to read in the information from the file first, then write to it.

Comment: thank you, an error is occurring at the end of my code: public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
  new project();
 } }

Comment: @j.aje alright I made some changes to the code above.  Also that error sounds separate from what this is.  It's normally better to not throw Exception as it's not going to let you know specifically where the error is occurring.  A try/catch statement is recommended.